# Allocating memory to a struct containing a matrix of struct, itself containing a matrix of integer

Tags: c, struct, allocation

So, I've some trouble understanding how am I suppose to allocate memory to a structure containing other structure.

here are my two struct :

```
typedef struct{
    int ** constraint;
    int max_domain;
}Constraint;

typedef struct{
    Constraint ** constraint_matrix;
    int max_var;
}Constraint_mat;
```

Now I try to create a function to allocate memory to a Constraint_mat, starting like this :

```
Constraint_mat * allocationConstraintMatrix(int max_var){
    printf("Initialisation Matrice de Contrainte : allocation mémoire\n");
    Constraint_mat * matrice_contrainte = malloc(max_var*(max_var-1)*(sizeof *matrice_contrainte))
    matrice_contrainte->max_var = max_var;
    matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix = malloc(max_var*sizeof(matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix));
    if(matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix == NULL){
        printf("Erreur allocation memoire matrice de contrainte\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < max_var; i++){
        matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix[i] = malloc(max_var*sizeof(matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix[i])); 
        if(matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix[i] == NULL){
            printf("erreur allocation memoire matrice de domaine\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    printf("Succes\n");
}
```

I don't understand how I'm suppose to allocate this. Do I have to prepare space for each constraint that will be in the matrix inside constraint_mat ?
I mean, I know that Constraint ** constraint_matrix will contain max_var*max_var Constraint, and that in each Constraint, int ** constraint will contain max_domain * max_domain int.
Does that mean that I have to prepare max_var * max_var * max_domain * max_domain * sizeof(int) for Constraint_mat ?

Comment: What is "something"?

Comment: Those are not "matrices" but pointers. A matrix would be something such as `int matrix[5][6]` with given dimensions.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Inside the malloc ? What I want to know.
And the somethingsomething one is the instanciation of what is inside my structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you store one dimension in each structure, I assume you consider those are square matrices.

I believe you use pointers of pointers for convenience, so you don't need not contiguous memory space, so you could allocate/deallocate memory for one constraint this way:

```
int allocate_Constraint(Constraint *pConstraint, int n)
{
    // You need room for n * n integers, right ?
    int *p = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        return 0; // memory insufficient => return false
    }

    // You need room for n pointers to integer
    pConstraint->constraint = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    if (pConstraint->constraint == NULL)
    {
        free(p);
        return 0; // memory insufficient => return false
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // Each line starts n integers farther than the previous one
        pConstraint->constraint[i] = p + n * i;
    }

    // Now it's good, your matrix is usable.
    pConstraint->max_domain = n;
    return 1;
}

void deallocate_Constraint(Constraint *pConstraint)
{
    if (pConstraint->max_domain > 0)
    {
        free(pConstraint->constraint[0]);
        free(pConstraint->constraint);
        pConstraint->constraint = NULL;
        pConstraint->max_domain = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Constraint c = {constraint: NULL, max_domain:0};
    if (allocate_Constraint(&c, 10))
    {
      // do stuff with c
      deallocate_Constraint(&c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And functions to allocate/deallocate constraint matrices could be:

```
int allocate_Constraint_mat(Constraint_mat *pConstraint_mat, int n)
{
    // You need room for n * n Constraint(s), right ?
    Constraint *p = malloc(n * n * sizeof(Constraint));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        return 0; // memory insufficient => return false
    }

    // You need room for n pointers to Constraint
    pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(Constraint *));
    if (pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix == NULL)
    {
        free(p);
        return 0; // memory insufficient => return false
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // Each line starts n Constraint(s) farther than the previous one
        pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix[i] = p + n * i;
    }

    // Initializing to empty matrices
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix[i][j].constraint = NULL;
            pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix[i][j].max_domain = 0;
        }
    }

    // Now it's good, your matrix is usable.
    pConstraint_mat->max_var = n;
    return 1;
}

void deallocate_Constraint_mat(Constraint_mat *pConstraint_mat)
{
    if (pConstraint_mat->max_var > 0)
    {
        free(pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix[0]);
        free(pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix);
        pConstraint_mat->constraint_matrix = NULL;
        pConstraint_mat->max_var = 0;
    }
}
```

Edit: Explanations for allocate_Constraint()

So you have a Constraint c, you want to allocate it with `allocate_Constraint(&c, n)`.
You need each `c.constraint[i]` to be valid so you can use it. So `c.constraint` need enough memory to store n pointers to `int`. Hence in the function there is:

```
pConstraint->constraint = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
```

Now you need all `c.constraint[i][j]` to be valid, and you need them to be independent values of course. So each `pConstraint->constraint[i]` (which is a pointer to `int`) to designate an address with room for n `int`. At total those are n * n `int`.

First method, which I do not recommend, would be n allocation of room for n `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    pConstraint->constraint[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

Second method, you allocate only once, and you dispatch the `c.constraint[i]`s in the large allocated memory space:

```
p = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    pConstraint->constraint[i] = p + i * n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works, but actually what bothered me was more how the memory is allocated here. If you malloc an array, you'll give him a certain size in the memory, but here, each block you give to the "big matrix" will contain another "little matrix" inside. So when I allocate the "big matrix" I wanted to know if I have to give him enough size to also contain each little matrice(i.e the size of each little matrix(that I have to determine manually) * their number), or just their number (number of matrix * whatever size it is).

Comment: @Traknir more clear with new edit?

Comment: yep thanks it helps !

Comment: @Traknir: one last thing, you don't need pointers to pointers in that case. Common practice is to declare `int * constraint;` in the struct, then you use only a single `malloc()` with: `c.constraint = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));` and you access each element as `c.constraint[i * n + j]`.

Comment: Why though ? Here I use a pointer to pointer to manipulate each constraint because I want it to looks like a matrix, because that's what makes the more sense here (Constraint represent a constraint between two variable, i and j). I've always been taught that what you code need to make sense. constraint[i][j] means you have a constraint between two variable i and j. If someone read this he understand. But if someone read constraint[i*n+j] it seems like constraint represent a constraint among other constraint, where in fact it's suppose to represent if i constraint j.

Comment: @Traknir I completely agree this is convenient for notation, but this costs you one memory allocation more. If you don't care the few memory more, then it is perfectly fine to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to write:

```
Constraint_mat * matrice_contrainte = malloc(1 * sizeof(Constraint_mat);
```

Which is simply going to allocate enough memory for one object of type `Constraint_mat` on the heap.

> Does that mean that I have to prepare max_var * max_var * max_domain * max_domain * sizeof(int) for Constraint_mat ?

Yes, but that does not change the size of the structures you are working with. **Each one of the pointers will point to a zone in memory that is not taken into account when you apply the sizeof() operator.** I am going to explain it in a simpler way, considering the second structure you are working with:

```
typedef struct{
    Constraint ** constraint_matrix;
    int max_var;
}Constraint_mat;
```

How much memory does it need? The answer is `sizeof(Constraint **) + sizeof(int)` (for every field in your structure) + a somewhat random amount, dependable on other factors. Usually, `sizeof(int) == 4` bytes on most modern machines, and the size of a pointer (ANY pointer, including pointers to massive structures, arrays and so forth) is always going to be the same, which is, for most purposes, `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` bytes.

With some simple addition, you can estimate your structure to be **at least** 4 + 4 = 8 bytes in size. This size is always going to be relatively constant and will never depend on the value of `max_var` you are using in your implementation. That means, if you want to insert N * N elements in your matrix ( `matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix`), you do not have to worry about the size of `Constraint **` to ever change.

Now, what's going to happen? When building the matrix, you have to consider allocating memory for the N pointers which represent the rows of your matrix:

`matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix = (Constraint **) malloc(N * sizeof(Constraint *))`

Afterwards, for each pointer you have to allocate more memory on the heap:

```
 int i = 0;
 for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix[i] = (Constraint *) malloc(N * sizeof(Constraint));
 }
```

From this point onwards, I hope the steps are going to be clear:

```
matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix[i][j]->constraint = (int **) malloc(N * sizeof(int *));
```

where j is iterating from 1 to N;

```
matrice_contrainte->constraint_matrix[i][j]->constraint[k] = (int *) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

where k is iterating from 1 to N.

In total, you are going to use N^4 memory (which is what you expected),  but you can't measure it using the sizeof() operator.

Make sure you do all the necessary `free()` calls.

I apologize in advance for redundancy in explanation and poor usage of English.

Comment: What is that assumption? `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4` I am sorry but no, this is not true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models As you can see the dummy LPP64 standard is not the only one!

Comment: In my answer I considered it was more important to prioritize simplicity over political corectness. I also apologize for my lack of experience in 64-bit computing.

Comment: It's bad to say something wrong for simplicity. `sizeof` exists because most types in C have platform dependent sizes.

Comment: @Betwixt Thank you for the explaination, that's what I was trying to understand.